# why is specific module not shown when using the lazyloading?

Tags: angular, typescript

When I am using load Children, the normal routes is 
working but the module is not working in angular 7.

This is for the Linux running Angular7.

*home-page.routing.module.ts:*

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page.component';
    const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
     component: HomePageComponent,
    }];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class HomePageRoutingModule { }

    export const routedComponents = [
      HomePageComponent,
    ];

    home-page.module.ts:
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChartsModule } from '../charts/charts.module';
    import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
    import { HomePageRoutingModule, routedComponents } from 
    './home-page-routing.module';
    import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
    @NgModule({
    imports: [
      ThemeModule,
      ChartsModule,
      HomePageRoutingModule,
      NgxPaginationModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
      routedComponents,
    ],
    })
    export class HomePageModule { }

    app-routing.module.ts:
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'asset',
     loadChildren: './home-page/home-page.module#HomePageModule',
    }];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {
    }
```

"The component is not working." 
I mentioned my code above.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "the module is not working" and "the component is not working"? Please share the error you are getting otherwise it is hard to help you efficiently.

Comment: Doesn't shown any error. The routes is working fine like 172.27.140.84:4200/#/asset but the html file is not shown in the browser.

Comment: One thing I noticed so far is, that your ```app.routing.module.ts``` should not use ```RouterModule.forChild()``` but rather ```forRoot```. What happens when you change that? If it's still not working, you would need to provide a bit more information on how the app.module.ts and app.component.html looks like etc.

Comment: Well then you would need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise it's just guessing without having the module, component and template definitions.

Comment: I tried "forRoot" in app.routing.module.ts. But it's not work. when i am clicking the navigation, the specific router called like
Header.component.html:
<div class="asset" (click)="assetInfo()">Asset Profile</div>
Header.component.ts: 
  assetInfo() {
    this.router.navigate(['/asset']);
  }